# convert an array to object and print result

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have this object and array data:

```
   stdClass Object
    (
        [meta_title] => title
        [meta_description] => 
        [categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => cat title
                    )
    
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] =>cat title 2
                    )
          
            )
    
        )
```

in action, I need to print `categories name`  using `foreach` method. how do can i print this?!

edit:

in my controller i have:

```
public function index()
{
    helper('text');
    $data = array(
        'meta_title' => 'title',
        'meta_description' => '',
        'categories' => $this->postModel->getNewsCategories(),      
    );

    return view('blog/index', array( 'categories' => (object)$data));
}
```

in view:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
  <a href="#"><?php echo esc($category->name);?></a>
<?end foreach;?>
```

But i see this error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: @u_mulder: please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code below will work

```
<?php foreach ($categories->categories as $category) } ?>
  <a href="#"><?php echo esc($category->name);?></a>
<?php end foeach; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get categories name using foreach loop.

```
foreach($YOU_STD_CLASS_DATA_VARIABLE->categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Thank You.